# Netbeans 8.0.2 Clean and Build then Run results in old code being run

Tags: java, netbeans

I'm new to NetBeans and Java.  I'm using NetBeans to build and run a Java Swing project for school.

I wrote my code in NetBeans and saved it.  Compiling from command line with `javac` is successful and the program runs as expected.  If I update the code and repeat the process from CLI, the new changes are reflected as expected.

If I make a code change in NetBeans, and `Clean and Build` (e.g. by pressing Shift+F11), then run from in NetBeans (e.g. by F6), the changes are **not** reflected.  No errors, I just get a `BUILD SUCCESSFUL` notification in Output.  But an older version of the application will run with no changes reflected.

I get around it by building from CLI but that's getting old really fast, it would be nice to be able to run from w/in the IDE.

Following is some context code.  It runs as desired.  As an example of my problem, note the button initialization in File 2.  If I change the ctor string arg, the change will not be reflected when I clean, build, and run in NetBeans, (or if I just build and run without clean).  However, it will be reflected if run from command line.

File 1:

```
/* pkg & import statements */

public class Project1Part1 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("Attempting to build frame...");
        buildFrame();
    }

    public static void buildFrame()
    {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Project 1, Part 1");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        GuiPanel guiPanel = new GuiPanel();
        frame.setContentPane(guiPanel);
        frame.setSize(640, 360);
        frame.setVisible(true);
        System.out.println("Frame built.");
    }
}
```

File 2:

```
/* pkg and import statements */

public class GuiPanel extends JPanel {

    public GuiPanel()
    {
        LayoutManager layoutMgr = new FlowLayout();
        setLayout(layoutMgr);

        Dimension buttonSize = new Dimension(150, 20);
        JButton cardPickerButton = new JButton("Card Picker");
        cardPickerButton.setPreferredSize(buttonSize);
        add(cardPickerButton);
    }
}
```

**Update:**
I upgraded my version of Ant from 1.9.4 to 1.9.6 as a shot in the dark based on other postings I saw, it made no difference.

**Update 2:**
I was using only the `Build` and `Clean and Build` options, which are not for compiling an application to run within the IDE.  When a file is saved, NetBeans automatically compiles the project by default, as per:
[the NetBeans documentation](https://netbeans.org/kb/docs/java/quickstart.html#run).  Likewise, if the user selects `Run`, all unsaved files will automatically be saved and compiled before NetBeans runs the application.  My problem was that I'm used to Clean and Build meaning something different, so I was running a Clean and Build every time I wanted to run the application in the IDE.  Once the `Clean and Build` or even the `Build` option is chosen in NetBeans, I haven't found a way to force recompilation for execution within the IDE other than making a trivial change to allow a resave of some file in the project.

**Update 3:**
Adding my project's `build.xml` by request.  I removed commented sections for readability.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project name="Project1Part1" default="default" basedir=".">
    <description>Builds, tests, and runs the project Project1Part1.</description>
    <import file="nbproject/build-impl.xml"/>
</project>
```

Comment: Could you post the part of your `build.xml` where the code is compiled/executed (include all parts which are needed to resolve variables, if used).

Comment: Added the whole file, excluding comments it's only 5 lines.  Not really sure what's supposed to happen in this file.  Is this used to tell NetBeans to update its own version of the application as well as the external build it generates?

Comment: Ok I tought it's a standalone Ant based project. Did you create this project with the Netbeans wizard? If you change the button text in `GuiPanel.java` and press `F6` is then `GuiPanle.java` saved and `ProjectPart1` executed?

Comment: Yes, I used the wizard.  And yes, pressing F6 does cause the project to compile with the changes visible.

Comment: Is your project referencing another project (in the "Libraries" section of the project properties)? Does it work if you _disable_ the "compile on save" feature? I have seen strange things happen when that is enabled (although mostly with Maven based projects). Did you enable the "Track Dependencies" option in the "Compiling" section of the project properties?

Comment: I haven't messed around with any settings at all.  This is a plain vanilla install of NetBeans 8.0.2 with a wizard template plain vanilla Java application.  I'm thinking of reinstalling NetBeans from scratch as per WillShackleford's answer below, just for kicks.

Comment: @fts_acer So `compile on save` is profed to be working. So where is your actual problem? Is it only that you expected `Clean and Build` to run your project?

Comment: I don't expect `Clean and Build` to run the project, but if I do `Clean and Build` and *then* `Run` (F6) then I would expect my changes to show up.  They do not.

Answer (score 4):

You should not have to do anything special to get the latest to run. Run  with or without a Build or a Clean and Build will run the latest version. I have had this kind of symptom before and it has always turned out there were multiple copies of the source and/or project files. Netbeans was using one to run and I was editing a copy in wrong directory expecting it to have an effect.

Try this:

1. From File menu select Close All Projects
2. From Window menu select Close All Documents
3. Use File -> Open Project to open the project again being careful to note the directory.
4. Open a source file by double clicking, one of the java files under source packages in the projects tab.
5. Make a change, Build then Run.
6. If your still having an issue, maybe there is something wrong with your installation of Netbeans. Consider closing Netbeans,  deleting the user config and cache directories. (http://wiki.netbeans.org/FaqWhatIsUserdir), and reinstalling Netbeans.

Answer (score 1):

In Maven based project, many cached output are in your “target” folder.

If clear doesn't work, just delete the **target** folder and run the project.

Answer (score -1):

Shift + f11

works just fine.

You are very welcome/n